# PHP Singleton design pattern inheritance error

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, singleton

From php singleton class below

```
<?php
class Singleton
{
    /**
     * @var Singleton The reference to *Singleton* instance of this class
     */
    private static $instance;

    /**
     * Returns the *Singleton* instance of this class.
     *
     * @return Singleton The *Singleton* instance.
     */
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (null === static::$instance) {
            static::$instance = new static();
        }

        return static::$instance;
    }

    /**
     * Protected constructor to prevent creating a new instance of the
     * *Singleton* via the `new` operator from outside of this class.
     */
    protected function __construct()
    {
    }
}
```

I am trying to inherit new child class

```
class SingletonChild extends Singleton {
}
```

but when I do testing

```
$obj = Singleton::getInstance();
$obj_two = SingletonChild::getInstance();
var_dump($obj === Singleton::getInstance());             // bool(true)
var_dump($obj === $obj_two);   // false
```

I'm getting php fatal error.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot access  property
>   SingletonChild::$instance

Comment: im testing with `$obj = Singleton::getInstance();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inheriting Singleton `class` in PHP is difficult, event in PHP 7.0, but you can do this with some changes on your class to work.

first make your `Singleton` `class` to `abstract`

```
abstract class Singleton {

}
```

change your `$instance` variable to array `$instance(s)`

```
private $instances = [];
```

Now change `getInstance()` method like below

```
public static function getInstance() {
  if (!isset(self::$instances[static::class]) {
    self::$instances[static::class] = new static();
  }

  return self::$instances[static::class];
}
```

And change your test

> remember now you can't call `Singleton:: getInstance()` due to **abstract**

```
class SingletonChild extends Singleton {
}

class SingletonChildTwo extends SingletonChild {
}

$obj = SingletonChild::getInstance();
$obj_two = SingletonChildTwo::getInstance();
var_dump($obj === SingletonChild::getInstance()); // true
var_dump($obj === $obj_two); // will -> false
```

Answer (score 4):

You made `$instance` private, which means it cannot be inherited. Change it to `protected`

```
protected static $instance;
```

The manual discusses the individual uses of visibility

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

So it looks like the hangup is in your edit

```
$obj = Singleton::getInstance();
$obj_two = SingletonChild::getInstance();
var_dump($obj === $obj_two);   // false
```

This will never be true. `getInstance` gets an instance of the current class. Since they are different classes they are not the same. Doing a test like this is sloppy, however. I would never do a test on an object like this. What would make more sense is to make sure that you're getting an instance of `Singleton` which can be done very easily like so

```
if($obj_two instanceof Singleton) // true
```

Because the child inherits the parent, it is an instance of the parent

Comment: no if i do protected then test will return true, true (both classes are equal).

Answer (score 1):

You should write:-

```
if (NULL == self::$instance) {
    self::$instance = new self();
}
return self::$instance;
```

You do not need to create child class of Singleton class. You can simply use below syntax to get object of Singleton class.

```
 Singleton::getInstance();
```

Simply define a method in any class which call `Singleton::getInstance();` and return the object.

Check [this link](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton/php/1) for more detail.

Answer (score -1):

## Singleton

This is one of the most popular patterns. When developing web applications, it often makes sense conceptually and architecturally to allow access to only one instance of a particular class (during runtime). The singleton pattern enables us to do this. Example:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Singleton class
 */
final class Product
{
    /**
     * @var self
     */
    private static $instance;
    /**
     * @var mixed
     */
    public $mix;
    /**
     * Return self instance
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!(self::$instance instanceof self)) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
    private function __construct() {
    }
    private function __clone() {
    }
}
$firstProduct = Product::getInstance();
$secondProduct = Product::getInstance();
$firstProduct->mix = 'test';
$secondProduct->mix = 'example';
print_r($firstProduct->mix);
// example
print_r($secondProduct->mix);
// example
```