# What is benefit of creating child class of Singleton Class?

Tags: class, oop, object, singleton, parent-child

Recently I have seen a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37138134/php-singleton-design-pattern-inheritance-error) regarding Singleton class.

OP has created a child class of Singleton class.

I told him that he do not need to create child class of Singleton class.

But In other answers supported child class concept. I searched on google but not getting any satisfactory answer.

Can someone please explain me to benefit of creating child class of singleton class?

Does it related to security concerns?

Your help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Singleton class cannot have more than one object but can have subclasses.

Think of an application which needs to have a logging functionality for example. We don't need to create n number of instances of a basic logger class so a singleton will suit this situation.

However, if i want to create loggers for different needs such as a rotating logger. Then we  can extend the basic logger class functionality by extending it from the base logger.